# Body missing in scala play post from swagger

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger, play-swagger

I have a controller

```
import models.UserRegistration
import javax.inject._
import play.api.mvc._
import com.example.WritableImplicits._

@Singleton
class UserController @Inject()(val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {

  def postExample = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    val userRegistration = UserRegistration.form.bindFromRequest().get
    Ok(userRegistration)
  }

  def getExample() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    val user1 : UserRegistration = new UserRegistration("ian", "ian@gmail.com", "123")
    val user2 : UserRegistration = new UserRegistration("asdfasdf", "asdfasdf@gmail.com", "1233123")
    val list: List[UserRegistration] = List(user1, user2)
    Ok(list)
  }
}
```

and a routes entry

```
###
#   summary: post a user
#   parameters:
#       - in: body
#         name: name
#         schema:
#           type: string
#         required: true
#         description: post a user in json format eg {name:"foo", email:"sdfsd", hash:"13123"}
#   tags:
#       - users
#   responses:
#       '200':
#         description: OK
#         content:
#            application/json:
#              schema:
#                type: string
###
+nocsrf
POST     /api/users                  controllers.UserController.postExample()
```

when posting in swagger like so [image]
I get a npe, debugging shows that my body is empty

[image]

looking at the post from swagger it appears the payload is missing

[image]

possibly there is an issue with the swagger docs above the routes entry?
but i am lost

Comment: Just guessing. Could be that you generate an open api spec with a different version that the one expected in swagger UI. Could show details about how you generate your Open API spec file and how swagger UI is being setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did indeed have the swaggerdoc wrong, rather than parameters it should have been

```
#   requestBody:
#     content:
#        application/json:
#          schema:
#            type: object
#          examples:
#            Basic:
#              value:
#                name:
#                   "123"
#                email:
#                   "9780987654321"
#                hash:
#                   "9780987654321"
```